# RStudio UTF-8 display issue with htmlwidget:datatable[package DT]

Tags: r, datatables, rstudio

I have a dataframe that contained some Chinese Chars that encoding with UTF-8.

For example, my dataframe as below

```
testdf <- data.frame(locationName= c("台北","新北市","台南市"), TEMP=c(30,29,28))
testdf
  locationName TEMP
1         台北   30
2       新北市   29
3       台南市   28


library(DT)
datatable(testdf)
```

I found the datatable can't display properly in R Viewer (In R console are okay)
when there have Chinese Char.

I check the index.html generate with datatable which default 
using "utf-8"

If I manually modify index.html manually to"charset=big5" and using the external browser to open, it okay to display. (Or choose "show in new windows" and using external browser with decode =big5.)

My questions is if any settings I can apply to make this work in R viewer without manually modify the html file manually or view in external browser?  Thanks for your help

Best Regards
James

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem (R version 3.2.2, DT version 0.1, Firefox 40.0 with text encoding set to Unicode).

Comment: Problem is actual in 3.2.2 and DT v 1.0. For example: `library(DT); data.frame(a=1:5, b=c("Один","Два","Три","Четыре","Пять")) -> ex; datatable(ex)` does not work.